# QT вызов функции во втором окне из первого окна

Tags: qt5

Может тема звучит смешно, но вроде такой элементарный код не работает, может я что то не уловил

Есть два окна..

**mainwindow.h**

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}    
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:  

explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
Auppt *auppt;
  и тп....
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

    ui->setupUi(this); // графический интерфейс     
    auppt = new Auppt ();  
 auppt->reNameLabels(); // **НЕ работает!**  
}
```

**auppt.h**

```
namespace Ui {class Auppt;}

class Auppt : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Auppt(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Auppt();
void reNameLabels();
    и тп..
```

**auppt.cpp**

```
Auppt::Auppt(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Auppt)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose); //удалять это окно при закрытии
}

void Auppt::reNameLabels() {    
    ui->nameEdit->setPlaceholderText("любой текст");       
    qDebug()<<"вызов функции";
}
```

uppt->reNameLabels(); // **НЕ работает!** Он даже не пытается вызвать функцию

Почему нельзя обращаться по такому указателю к соседнему окну?
нигде не нашел подобной проблемы в гугле...

Answer (score 1):

Все работает, невнимательность =(.
А я думал что только через сигналы и слоты нужно было как то вызывать функцию.